# 'It is necessary for job interviewees being punctual': Why isn't this grammatical?

Tags: infinitives, subjects, participles

> It is necessary for job interviewees ______ punctual because it will make a great impression.
>
> a. to be
>
> b. being
>
> c. are
>
> d. will be

The answer is 'a'. But I wonder why 'b' is wrong? (I know why 'c, d' are not the answer.)

Comment: We attempt to eliminate the grammar tag. (Almost) Please don't tag your questions with it. See [*A proposed solution to the Grammar dilemma*](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/a-proposed-solution-to-the-grammar-dilemma-please-contribute-your-answers-t?cb=1)

Answer (score 6):

If you write

> It is necessary for job interviewees *being punctual*...

The 'being punctual' is interpreted as a *participle phrase* modifying "*interviewees*".  The tight binding of those parts of the sentence prevents the "*being punctual*" from making the intended connection to "*necessary*", like the "*to be punctual*" would if you wrote:

> It is necessary for job interviewees *to be punctual*...

Comment: Hmmm. I don't agree there. If you use the first sentence then *being punctual* is a right dislocation clarifying the referent of *it*. I don't think any native speaker can parse the sentence so that *being punctual* is modifying *interviewees*.

Comment: @Araucaria "It is necessary for job interviewees being punctual to pay attention to other things as well". Of course, the original sentence did not leave that interpretation as an option.

Comment: @oerkelens Do you mean: ""It is necessary for job interviewees' being punctual to pay attention to other things as well"? (where there's an apostrophe after *interviewees*)? It sounds the same but the structure's different!

Comment: @oerkelens Hmmm can't tell if it's grammatical without the apostrophe there .... ? Interesting sentence!

Comment: @oerkelens That's an interesting sentence. Underlyingly it's  "[To pay attention to other things as well] is necessary for job interviewees['] being puntual. Here the *for* is the preposition and not the subordinator.

Answer (score 1):

> It is necessary for job interviewees to be punctual.

This type of sentence is called an *extraposition*. We use extrapositions like this because it is difficult for listeners to process (understand) sentences if they have an infinitive clause as a Subject.

This sentence means:

- [For job interviewees to be punctual] is necessary.

However, no native speaker would say that sentence, because it is difficult to understand it. In this sentence the infinitive clause has a Subject, *interviewees*. If an infinitive clause has a Subject, we need to use the word *for* before the Subject:

- It is difficult to understand.
- It is difficult for people to understand.

To make an extraposition sentence, we use a dummy Subject, *it* and put the infinitive clause at the end of the sentence.

- [To be there on time] is important
- **It** is important [to be there on time].

We can also make extrapositions with finite clauses:

- [That he was late] surprised me.
- It surprised me [that he was late].

Notice that in all these sentences, the word *it* has no meaning. We just use it to fill the Subject position in the sentence. It doesn't mean anything.

Now, we can't make extrapositions with *-ing* clauses (gerund-participle clauses) in the same way if the *-ing* clause has a Subject.

- [My being in charge] is necessary
- *It is necessary [my being in charge]. (ungrammatical)

We can make a sentence that looks very similar though:

- It's necessary, my being in charge.

Here *my being in charge* is a *right dislocation*. It explains what the pronoun *it* refers to. It is a bit like saying:

- She's a fantastic swimmer, Mary.

In this sentence, *Mary* explains exactly who *she* refers to. Right dislocations are usually considered very informal and normally only happen in speech, not normally in writing.

The Original Poster needs to use option (a) here

Comment: Does not answer the question, other than to say "we can't" do such-and-such. The OP asks why.

Answer (score -1):

"It is + adjective + to-infinitve" is a fixed sentence pattern.

-It's difficult/interesting to learn a foreign language.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It just affirms the construction of answer 'a'.